# What does QCL quasi-colocation actually mean?

Tags: digital-communications, mimo

Quasi-colocation is a concept stated in 5G NR specifications. But I'm not quite sure about what it actually means. Is one of its meanings that the propagation channel of the physical channel has the same correlation in frequency domain or time domain with that of some reference signal? How to prove this mathematically? Does the proof still hold when precoding is applied to one of the physical channel or signal? What if there's correlation between transmit antennas and receive antennas? And what if precoding varies between different PRGs?

Comment: https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_QCL.html#What_does_it_really_mean

Comment: Thanks. If write down the channel correlation between subcarriers, precoding weights are present. So will precoding affect the correlation especially when precoding is done in PRG granularity?

Comment: I don't really get the question. It is obvious that (1) if your precoding is unity, no impact; but (2) in general between having and not having precoding, the spatial correlation is not the same.

Comment: However, the usual definition of channel correlation does not contain the precoding which can be (and must be in the case of 5G NR) removed by using pilots.

Comment: I mean correlation between subcarriers in frequency domain since it's combinations of propagation channels weighted by precoding weights which may be wideband or vary with PRGs. I want to make sure precoding doesn't change the channel correlation in frequency domain by proving it mathematically, so the correlation of some reference signal may be used for some QCLed physical channel.

Comment: If you don't remove precoding, the spatial correlation (if I presume correctly the definition) does depend on the very precoding.